# use of other functions alongside analog input function

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have an analog input object (winsound) taking samples and performing a task on audio in MATLAB.

```
set(AI, 'SamplesAcquiredFcnCount',num_samples)
set(AI, 'SamplesAcquiredFcn',{@function1,AI,num_samples})
```

My understanding is that the analog input object just keeps taking samples, and hence **function1** keeps being called when samples reach the set number. So ***it has 'priority'.***

Now I have another function (**function2**), that I want to **continuously process** the (global) variables that the **function1** updates. My problem is that in my current implementation function2 won't "come back" and look at the updated variables from the analog input.

I want to call function2 continuously up to a certain duration or condition, but **how do I make it see the updated variables from the analog input function1**? (they are already global, but once function2 has begun it doesn't get the updated variables, only as they were when it started).

I've tried to look into stuff in parallel computing toolbox to help me here, but haven't found anything. I really appreciate any help! This will really piece my project together

Answer (score 2):

In the end the best way to ensure good side-by-side operation is just to call function2 inside function1. Since function1 is nicely controlled as a callback in the analog input object, this is the safest way to go about it.